# vim: How to find/jump to function call (not definition!)

Tags: vim, tags, ctags

Via `ctags` I can jump to the definition of a function. But how I can jump to the places where a function is used?

Comment: Over on [vi.se]: [How to jump to function call?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4955/205)